# How to make an image hyperlink in <h2> tag where <h2> consist of text and image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is an `<h2>` tag which consist of text as well as image. I want to make the image as a hyper link without including the text.

```
<h2>Sample text<img src="test.png"></h2>
```

I tried to put anchor tag using `<div>`, `<span>` etc. but it break the `<h2>` into  2 lines.

```
<h2><nav>Sample text</nav><nav><a href=""><img src="test.png"></a></nav></h2>
```

I could only make the entire `<h2>` as hyper link and not the image inside.

Is there any way to make an image inside `<h2>` tag without breaking the `<h2>` tag into two lines?

Comment: Doesn't break into two lines here: https://jsfiddle.net/5vnsxd41/

Comment: Given your tags are you trying to make this work using Javascript, or are you just struggling typing in an `<a>` element?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan When I was trying something else I just come across this and trying to put<a> inside <h2>

Answer (score 2):

The code in your question breaks to multiple lines as you've added an unecessary `<nav>` tag to it.

To achieve what you need without the line break, use jQuery to select the `img` within the `h2`, then you can use `wrap()` to add the anchor. Try this:

```js
$('h2 img').wrap('<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"></a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Sample text<img src="test.png"></h2>
```

Note that the link above doesn't actually work when clicked because of the `SAMEORIGIN` `X-Frame-Options` that the SO domain has, but it would work in a full window.

Comment: Why would you do that instead of just writing it down plain in HTML? The problem is he is using additional tags in his h2, not the anchor tag.

Comment: @Danmoreng the question originally had `javascript` and `jQuery` tags - hence I assumed the OP was attempting this in JS code. You're right, without those tags it makes no sense as the OP can just type the HTML in.

Comment: In fact I rolled back the edit that removed the tags as they were by third party who have obviously made assumptions that the OP has not verified

Answer (score 0):

Using only css. Here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/5jqq1mc8/1/)

```
<h2><a href="">Sample text<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_o15gKsnxOAVksRFPKYBUmD5TSkf2twg62_zYnJSdOGueQ03zB8sR05zZyyLXycAtck=w300"></a></h2>
```

And the trick is only in your css:

```
 a{
    line-height: 0; 
    font-size: 0;
    color: transparent; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float:left` for both `nav` and `img` for a simple solution.

```css
h2 nav, h2 img{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<h2><nav>Sample text</nav><nav><a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"></a></nav></h2>
```

Answer (score -1):

The way I do this is.

```
<a href="#"><img src="#" height=_  width=_ ></a>
```

There are many other way. Using jquery as mentioned earlier.
But if you are a beginner.. this could help you.

Comment: This does not have <h2> tag

Answer (score -1):

Hope this works. Make sure to write this as your basis. This is just a sample.

```css
.content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 90px;
  background: #ff9600;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-block {
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
}

.content-block img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-block"> 
    <img src="images/sample.png" width="280" height="" alt="" />
    <h2>ensure much better learning and development</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <img> tag should be inside <h2>